# Whats the event when an app exits in Cordova?

Tags: ios, events, cordova

I am writing an iOS app using Apache Cordova. There is onDeviceReady event that lets me know when I can start calling my code.

Is there an event that I can handle that tells me that the application is exiting. Not resume or pause because those are fired when an application goes to the background and then returns to the foreground.

I want to do some clean up work when an app exits.

Is there an event for this? Which one is it?

Comment: Have you looked at [addEventListener](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html) for `exit`?

Comment: That is when using an InAppBrowser. I am not using an InAppBrowser.

Comment: there is no such event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No such event . When u exit you loose control over the app . You can add event listener on pause and resume but not on exit